# Split torch tensor : max size and end of the sentence

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, tensor, torch

I would like to split a tensor into several tensors with torch on Python.
The tensor is the tokenization of a long text.

First here is what I had done:

```
tensor = tensor([[ 3746,  3120,  1024,  ...,  2655, 24051,  2015]]) #size 14714

result = tensor.split(510)
```

It works but now I would like to refine this, and make it so that it can't split in the middle of a sentence but at the **end of a sentence**, so recognizing the dot '.' (token 1012). Of course all the tensor will not be the same size but will have to respect a **maximum size** (510 for example).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

i tried it out a solution but its not straightforward but does the trick

oo and you might want to install this library [more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), used this to do the split

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast
import typer
import torch

from pathlib import Path
from typing import List
from more_itertools import split_after

def open_txt(txt_path:Path) -> List[str]:
    with open(txt_path, 'r') as txt_file:
        return [txt.replace('\n', '') for txt in txt_file.readlines()]
    
def pad_token(input_ids, pad_length=510):
    split_input_ids = list(split_after(input_ids, lambda x: x == 1012))
    
    # Pad to 510
    new_input_ids = []
    for ids in split_input_ids:
        ids += [0] * (pad_length - len(ids))
        new_input_ids.append(ids)
        
    return new_input_ids

def main(
    text_path:Path=typer.Option('sent.txt')
):
    tokenizer:BertTokenizerFast = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    
    sentence = open_txt(text_path)
    sentence = ''.join(sentence)
    
    features = tokenizer(
        sentence, padding='max_length'
    )
    
    input_ids = features['input_ids']
    
    new_input_ids = pad_token(input_ids, pad_length=600)
    # print(tokenizer.decode(new_input_ids[0]))
    # convert to torch
    new_input_ids = torch.tensor(new_input_ids)
    # features['input_ids'] = new_input_ids
    
    print(new_input_ids[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    typer.run(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a built-in function in PyTorch to do what you asked, which involves several steps:

1. Count how many sentences there are; assign this number to `n_sents`.
2. Compute the sentences' lengths and the indices where they start in `tensor`. Let 1-D tensors `length` and `start` store the lengths and the indices respectively. In other words, `length[i]` and `start[i]` are the length and the start index of the `i`-th sentence respectively, i.e. `tensor[start[i]]` is the first token of the `i`-th sentence.
3. Create a result tensor `result = torch.full((n_sents, max_len), pad_value)` where `max_len = max(length)`.
4. Assign `result[i, :length[i]] = tensor[start[i] : start[i]+length[i]]` for all `i` in `range(n_sents)`.

A side comment: detecting sentence ending by recognizing periods doesn't always work e.g., *I went to dr. Smith yesterday.* is one sentence but has two periods.